# How can I fix the MySQL 'access denied' errors after db restore?

Tags: mysql, access-denied

I exported all databases of a MySQL server by:

```
    mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /tmp/dbs.sql
```

Then I copied the file (by scp) on another server, which has the same MySQL version, and imported it with:

```
    mysql -u root -p < dbs.sql
```

I can access to MySQL only as root. With other users, I obtain:

```
    ~$ mysql -u jag -p
    Enter password: 
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jag'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However, selecting all users in mysql.user table, I can see that all user accounts where imported. So, how can I overcome this problem, without resetting all user passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify username and password, you can try this:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME
```

**Note that there is no space between -p parameter and password**!

You can check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I obtain the same error.
$ mysql -u jag -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 jag
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jag'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Unfortunately I obtain the same error. 
$ mysql -u jag -pmypass -h 127.0.0.1 jag 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jag'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Maybe it doesn't import correctly passwords?

Comment: I found the problem: mysql should be restarted for applying changes with new (imported) users:

$ sudo service mysql restart

Answer (score 0):

After following all the similar answers for this issue, I've solved it in CentOS with this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score -1):

please make sure to grant privileges to that user u want to restore with, in this case 'jag'